# The maps $\iota_F: F \to X$ (where $F \in \mathcal{F})$ coinduce a topology $\mathcal{T}'$ on $X$. Show that $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ a collection of subsets of $X$ equipped with the subspace topology. The inclusion maps $\iota_F: F \to X$ (where $F \in \mathcal{F})$ coinduce a topology $\mathcal{T}'$ on $X$. Show that $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$.

The coinduced topology is precisely those sets $U \subset X$ for which $\iota_F^{-1}[U] \in \mathcal{T}_F$ where $\mathcal{T}_F$ is the subspace topology on $F$. Now as $\iota_F^{-1}[U]=F \cap U$ this set is in $\mathcal{T}_F$ if and only if $F\cap U= F \cap V$ for $V \in \mathcal{T}$.

Now my objective is to show that if I take an arbitary open set $U \in \mathcal{T}$, then if I can show that $U \in \mathcal{T}'$ I'm done.

Now let $U \in \mathcal{T}$. Now I think I should consider $F \cap U \in \mathcal{T}_F$ and since this can be exrpessed as $F \cap V$ for $V \in \mathcal{T}$ I should be able to conclude something from here, but I cannot see how I can go further?

Comment: If $U \in \mathcal{T}$ by continuity of all $\iota_F$ (or equivalently by the defintion of the subspace topology) we have that $\iota_F^{-1}[U]= U \cap F$ is open in $F$ for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$ so **by definition** $U \in \mathcal{T}'$. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that $U\in\mathcal T'$ means that, for each $F\in\mathcal F$, $U\cap F$ is an open subset of $F$. And it *is* an open subset of $F$, since $U\in\mathcal T$.

Comment: This indeed comes from the definition of subspace topology. It would seem that these intersections could also be empty, but that wouldn't be a problem since we consider the empty set to be open right?

Comment: Yes. Actually, we don't just “consider” the open set to be open. It *is* open by the definition of open set and the definition of topology.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This makes me wonder what would $\bigcup_{F \in \mathcal{F}} U \cap F$ be? I'm not sure if this is even well defined.

Comment: Yes, it is well-defined. It is equal to $\left(\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F}F\right)\cap U$.

Comment: I somehow tought that this would equal $U$. Since $U \in \mathcal{T}'$ means that for each $F \in \mathcal{F}$ the intersection $U \cap F$ is open in $F$ I considered that $U = \bigcup_{F \in \mathcal{F}} U \cap F$.

Comment: Why? If $\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F}F\ne X$ and if $U$ contains some element $x\in X\setminus\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F}F$, there is no ways that $\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F}U\cap F=U$, since $x\notin\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F}U\cap F$. But if $\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F}F=X$ then, yes, you always have $U=\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F}U\cap F$.